# Issues with unintended output activation in RF module circuit

Tags: rf, remote-control

I'm encountering problems with my RF module circuit for a cold pyro igniter using HT12E:

Unintended Flash on Power On:When powering the receiver, the output flashes without button press.

Continuous Output When Remote is Turned Off:After turning off the remote, the output remains high without button press.

Circuit Components:RF Module,HT12E, HT12D, Relay.

Am facing the problem since circuit construction.

Seeking guidance on preventing unintended output activation. Any insights or solutions appreciated.

Circuit Schematic :-
[[image: Original Source: Electrogadget][1]]

Image Source: [Electrogadget](https://circuitdiagrams.in/fm-remote-encoder-decoder-circuit/)

[image]

[image]

Power source:

For transmitter 9v battery connected to 5v voltage Regulator(7805)
Receiver side is connected to 5v mobile charger.

Comment: johnson veigas - Hi, For starters: (a) Please edit the question to add your schematic, details of the power sources for transmitter & receiver, and some photos of the physical h/w. (b) Has this been a problem since the hardware was first constructed? Or did it only start after some point? (And in that case, what changed just before this behaviour started?). (d) Is the described behaviour 100% consistent all the time now, or is it intermittent? (e) When you said "*When Remote is Turned Off {...}*" do you mean the remote *transmitter* or the remote *receiver*, or ...? Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: (P.S. If you copy / adapt any material from elsewhere into a post, e.g. schematics etc., please make sure to correctly reference the source(s) according to [this site rule](/help/referencing), naming the source author / website and giving its original link. Thanks.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Step #1 when doing anything RF: do not create a "rat nest" of long cable loops all over the place or they may act as antennas. Ideally avoid breadboards entirely, they are mostly good for creating additional problems on top of the actual problem(s) you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any basic data radio receiver (and decoder) will produce a random data output in the absence of an input RF signal from the encoder/transmitter. Just think about a regular audio radio when it's not tuned to a station; you hear noise and, that noise (when amplified) will be converted to a data stream in your decoder circuit and, produce random strings of data.

At some point, a contiguous string of random data will match the data needed to activate or deactivate your igniter. Here's an image from [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/110556/20218) that might help show what I mean: -

[image]

This is for an FM radio transmission and receiver but it will be a similar problem with AM transmission and reception; in the absence of a valid transmission, the automatic gain control in the receiver will max-out and cause random data to appear at the output. At some point that random data will match valid data.

For a robust radio data transmission, you need to go a lot further and use a much more sophisticated radio data transmission so that it significantly minimizes the occurrences of random noise being seen as a valid string.

One of the other things you can use is carrier detect (if your radio receiver has it) and gate your received data signal so that background random noise is prevented from being read by the decoder. You can also use better decoding that checks the validity of each bit received at several points in the bit's time frame.

A CRC checksum is also a useful thing to add to your transmission. Checking for a 2nd repeat valid transmission straight after the first valid transmission also goes a long way to make things more robust.

Answer (score 0):

As the other [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/694630/101063) already mentions, adding a CRC checksum would be useful to protect against random noise and/or inteference being detected as a valid message.

From a quick look at the HT12E / HT12D devices used for the encoding / decoding I can't see any mention of a CRC being used on the protocol.

Are you able to change away from the HT12E / HT12D devices and existing 433 MHz RF modules for a microcontroller based approach?

There are are some microcontrollers which have a built-in radio module which can be used on the 533 MHz RF band. E.g. the TI [CC430F613x, CC430F612x, CC430F513x MSP430™ SoC With RF Core](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau259e/slau259e.pdf) MCUs which have a built in sub-1-GHz radio core based upon of the [CC1101 Low-power Sub-1 GHz wireless transceiver](https://www.ti.com/product/CC1101).

If you use a microcontroller based approach the benefits could be:

1. Can create a custom protocol which includes a CRC to filter out corrupt messages, or even a ECC to be able to correct some errors.
2. Allows the encoder / decoder and RF modules to be combined.
3. The same hardware module to be used for both transmit or receive, with software to configure as a transmitter or receiver.

The downside is having to program software.